# Why is this code giving an "unreachable code" error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unreachable-code

I can't seem to find a way to fix this problem. All I'm doing is declaring an integer and the compiler is telling me that the code is unreachable.

```java
class MyStack {

    Object[] myStack = new Object[50];

    private void push(Object obj) {
        int count = 50;
        while (count > 0) {
            myStack[count] = myStack[count - 1];
            count--;
        }
        myStack[0] = obj;
    }

    private Object pop() {
        return myStack[0];
        int count2 = 0; // Unreachable code
    }
}
```

Comment: You returned from the pop() method. Anything after that is unreachable.

Comment: Because it is `unreachable code`.

Comment: What Jim said. A "return" means "end of method".

Comment: Thanks Jim.
Eng. telling me the problem i asked about isn't helpful..

Comment: every statement after the return is just unreachable code...

Comment: The obvious error here is that the class has the private access modifier; you can’t have that with a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you `return` from a method, you return to the method that called the method in the first place.  Any statements you place after a return would be meaningless, as that is code that you can't reach without seriously violating the program counter (may not be possible in Java).

Answer (score 8):

Quoting a comment on the question by [Jim H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65750/jim-h):

> You returned from the pop() method. Anything after that is unreachable.

Comment: heh, sorry i couldnt resist ... i know this is not the place to discuss this, but honestly i find it annoying to see a question `unanswered` and then find out there were several great answers posted as comments. why do that ? to avoid the risk of downvotes? IMHO it only makes it harder to find a good answer. sorry again

Comment: Can anyone enumerate on other types of conditions leading to unreachable codes? for example : 'while(true){} S.O.P. '//Unreachable?

Answer (score 1):

Unreachable code results in compiler error in Java.

In your program the line

```
int count2 = 0;
```

will never be reached since it is after the return statement.

Place this line above the return statement to work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple explanation in plain English would be the following:

```
 private Object pop(){
    return myStack[0];
    int count2 = 0; //Unreachable Code
}
```

method `private Object pop(){}`  is looking for a return type `Object` and you just gave that return type by writing `return myStack[0];` .So your method does not necessarily reach `int count2 = 0;` because it assumed that the method already reached its goal.

Answer (score 0):

The last statement in the function should be a return statement.

Linting tools would flag it since it messes with the allocation of new memory after the counter scope ends.

Answer (score -1):

Declare before return myStack[0] that fixes

Comment: there is no need to do this because the variable `myStack` is declrred previously. And the right answer is the one which is accepted.